# How to auto insert the current user into my db when inserting records from Frontend

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have columns Month and Values on my db.Am inserting month and values from front-end to my db.I need my current user(username) also to be stored in a seperate column whenever I pass my month and values from front end.

Another question is that,When my month is entered once ,I should not be able to  enter the same month again..How to set validations for this??

I got stuck at this level.Can anyone help me sorting this?

Html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>FRONTEND VALUES BP</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>BLOOD PRESSURE</p>
<form action="index" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Month1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="JanMonth" placeholder="enter your month"></br></br>
    <label>Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="JanValue" placeholder="enter your value"></br></br>

    <label>Month2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="FebMonth" placeholder="enter your month"></br></br>
    <label>Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="FebValue" placeholder="enter your value"></br></br>

    <label>Month3:</label>
    <input type="text" name="MarMonth" placeholder="enter your month"></br></br>
    <label>Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="MarValue" placeholder="enter your value"></br></br>

    <label>Month4:</label>
    <input type="text" name="AprMonth" placeholder="enter your month"></br></br>
    <label>Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="AprValue" placeholder="enter your value"></br></br>

    <label>Month5:</label>
    <input type="text" name="MayMonth" placeholder="enter your month"></br></br>
    <label>Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="MayValue" placeholder="enter your value"></br></br>

    <label>Month6:</label>
    <input type="text" name="JunMonth" placeholder="enter your month"></br></br>
    <label>Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="JunValue" placeholder="enter your value"></br></br>

    <label>Month7:</label>
    <input type="text" name="JulMonth" placeholder="enter your month"></br></br>
    <label>Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="JulValue" placeholder="enter your value"></br></br>

    <label>Month8:</label>
    <input type="text" name="AugMonth" placeholder="enter your month"></br></br>
    <label>Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="AugValue" placeholder="enter your value"></br></br>

    <label>Month9:</label>
    <input type="text" name="SepMonth" placeholder="enter your month"></br></br>
    <label>Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="SepValue" placeholder="enter your value"></br></br>

    <label>Month:10</label>
    <input type="text" name="OctMonth" placeholder="enter your month"></br></br>
    <label>Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="OctValue" placeholder="enter your value"></br></br>

    <label>Month11:</label>
    <input type="text" name="NovMonth" placeholder="enter your month"></br></br>
    <label>Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="NovValue" placeholder="enter your value"></br></br>

    <label>Month12:</label>
    <input type="text" name="DecMonth" placeholder="enter your month"></br></br>
    <label>Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="DecValue" placeholder="enter your value"></br></br>
    <input type="submit" name="sign-in" value="Sign In">
    <a href="input/graphvalue">
        <button type="button"><span>GRAPH</span></button>
    </a>
</form>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models



class graphinput(models.Model):

  Month = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  Values = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from input.models import graphinput
from.utils import get_plot



def index(request):

 if request.method == 'POST':
     JanMonth = request.POST['JanMonth']
     JanValue = request.POST['JanValue']

     FebMonth = request.POST['FebMonth']
     FebValue = request.POST['FebValue']

     MarMonth = request.POST['MarMonth']
     MarValue = request.POST['MarValue']

     AprMonth = request.POST['AprMonth']
     AprValue = request.POST['AprValue']

     MayMonth = request.POST['MayMonth']
     MayValue = request.POST['MayValue']

     JunMonth = request.POST['JunMonth']
     JunValue = request.POST['JunValue']

     JulMonth = request.POST['JulMonth']
     JulValue = request.POST['JulValue']

     AugMonth = request.POST['AugMonth']
     AugValue = request.POST['AugValue']

     SepMonth = request.POST['SepMonth']
     SepValue = request.POST['SepValue']

     OctMonth = request.POST['OctMonth']
     OctValue = request.POST['OctValue']

     NovMonth = request.POST['NovMonth']
     NovValue = request.POST['NovValue']

     DecMonth = request.POST['DecMonth']
     DecValue = request.POST['DecValue']
     
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=JanMonth,Values=JanValue)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=FebMonth,Values=FebValue)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=MarMonth,Values=MarValue)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=AprMonth,Values=AprValue)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=MayMonth,Values=MayValue)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=JunMonth,Values=JunValue)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=JulMonth,Values=JulValue)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=AugMonth,Values=AugValue)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=SepMonth,Values=SepValue)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=OctMonth,Values=OctValue)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=NovMonth,Values=NovValue)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=DecMonth,Values=DecValue)
     graphplot.save();
     print('SUCCESFULLY ADDED')
     return redirect('graphvalue')

 else:
    return render(request, 'bp.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a userfield in your model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class graphinput(models.Model):
  user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  Month = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  Values = models.IntegerField()
```

In views you need to -:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from input.models import graphinput
from.utils import get_plot



def index(request):

 if request.method == 'POST':
     JanMonth = request.POST['JanMonth']
     JanValue = request.POST['JanValue']

     FebMonth = request.POST['FebMonth']
     FebValue = request.POST['FebValue']

     MarMonth = request.POST['MarMonth']
     MarValue = request.POST['MarValue']

     AprMonth = request.POST['AprMonth']
     AprValue = request.POST['AprValue']

     MayMonth = request.POST['MayMonth']
     MayValue = request.POST['MayValue']

     JunMonth = request.POST['JunMonth']
     JunValue = request.POST['JunValue']

     JulMonth = request.POST['JulMonth']
     JulValue = request.POST['JulValue']

     AugMonth = request.POST['AugMonth']
     AugValue = request.POST['AugValue']

     SepMonth = request.POST['SepMonth']
     SepValue = request.POST['SepValue']

     OctMonth = request.POST['OctMonth']
     OctValue = request.POST['OctValue']

     NovMonth = request.POST['NovMonth']
     NovValue = request.POST['NovValue']

     DecMonth = request.POST['DecMonth']
     DecValue = request.POST['DecValue']
     
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=JanMonth,Values=JanValue,user=request.user)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=FebMonth,Values=FebValue,user=request.user)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=MarMonth,Values=MarValue,user=request.user)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=AprMonth,Values=AprValue,user=request.user)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=MayMonth,Values=MayValue,user=request.user)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=JunMonth,Values=JunValue,user=request.user)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=JulMonth,Values=JulValue,user=request.user)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=AugMonth,Values=AugValue,user=request.user)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=SepMonth,Values=SepValue,user=request.user)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=OctMonth,Values=OctValue,user=request.user)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=NovMonth,Values=NovValue,user=request.user)
     graphplot = graphinput.objects.create(Month=DecMonth,Values=DecValue,user=request.user)
     graphplot.save();
     print('SUCCESFULLY ADDED')
     return redirect('graphvalue')

 else:
    return render(request, 'bp.html')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!!Another question is that,When my month is entered once ,I should not be able to enter the same month again..How to set validations for this??